# MySQL Query to calculate Fiscal Year/Quarter/Week/Month

Tags: mysql

I need to display the fiscal month based on a date field that I have.

Our fiscal year starts on January 1st and is a standard 4/4/5 week quarter with the final day of the year on 12/31 no matter the number of weeks in the last period so the fiscal month will not always align with the calendar year.

For example in 2015, the last day of `fiscal January is 1/30/15`, `February is 2/27/15`, & `April is 4/3/15`

Can this be done using a single MySQL query statement where it list me out put as

```
GIVEN_DATE
FISCAL_YEAR 
FISCAL_QUARTER  
FISCAL_WEEK 
FISCAL_MONTH
```

Comment: Your example for April should be 4/30/15 instead of 4/3/15?
Beginning January 1st + 4weeks is 1/29/15?
Does your fiscal month/week end always on Fridays?
Please provide the complte ruleset which has to implemented

Comment: Hi Prasad, Were you able to figure it out how to do it?